# Longpress event on Google Maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm creating a web app for mobile phones where if they longpress a certain part of the map, something happens. Unfortunately I can't use a window.setTimeout(..) with a mousedown/mouseup combination because the Maps API doesn't contain those events as it would disrupt the drag events. Is there another way to do this? There has to be a way because the Maps webapp on mobile pops up the same menu when you longpress as right-click on Google maps for computers - just don't know how! Please let me know!!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason you can't use the DOM mousedown/mouseup events rather the the Maps API events to detect a long press. You can even use the Maps API to attach the listeners, for example (assuming you have  as the element containing the map):

```
 google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), 'mousedown', function () { console.log("Test") });
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent question. After much digging, I found the following page on touch and gesture events for Android and iPhone. Hopefully this list will be of some use to you:

[http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20140729201632/http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html)

To elaborate, you're probably going to want to handle the touchstart and touchend events, perhaps keeping track of the position of the "cursor" at each to determine if it was a drag or simply a press. Good luck, and I don't blame you if you don't consider this a definitive answer. :P

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give that a shot tomorrow and I'll let you know!

Comment: No problem. :) I'm curious to hear how it goes.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work :( ..I'll keep searching and hopefully I'll find something. Thanks anyways though!